# SQL Server Always On - security updates without DB disconnecting from application

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups, high-availability

Our real-time communication application relies on database access, and it cannot be disconnected from the DB when running.
Recently our customer’s DB maintenance team notified us that the DB will be occasionally disconnected from the app, possibly also during application working hours - due to security upgrade reasons. The blackout gap can be c.a. 2-minute.

The question is:
Is it possible with SQL Server Always On setup (this is what they have) to maintain **uninterrupted** DB access (from application perspective) during upgrading nodes of the SQL cluster ?
Our understanding is that SQL Server **Always On** setup (as the name indicates) should be always available, regardless of a single node failure, or in case of intentionally executed upgrade on subsequent individual nodes (even if taking these offline, if required). We believe this should be possible with some kind of setup.
Or alternatively does the “Always” mean “**almost** always” (with e.g. 2 minute time required to fail over to some standby instance, etc..) ?

Can anyone confirm possibility to update software of **individual nodes** of the cluster (Windows Updates + SQL Server engine updates) one-by-one, eventually upgrading all nodes – with maintaining uninterrupted database access by the application during this process ?

Could anyone share a link to documentation or article describing how to configure this capability? (We plan to share these links with the DB maintenance team).

Comment: Which kind of AlwaysOn do you use exactly, FailOverCluster or HighAvailability Group? Your description sound like FailOver Cluster and in this case you get a downtime, because cluster has to stop virtual SQL name, IP, disks and SQL server service on one node and start it on another one.

Comment: @Mainecoon21 - even Availability Groups make the database unavailable as it moves the primary role from one server to another. That is, from the perspective of a connecting application, an FCI and an AG will present, for almost all intents and purposes, the same behavior.

Comment: OP - "Always On" is a Microsoft marketing term, not a literal description of availability SLAs.

Comment: @BenThul, I'm aware of that, but as a basic rule AG doesn't need 2 or 3 minutes for a switch (or even more depends on dif. things) because all databases are already online compared to FCI which has to bring them online. Accordingly to my experience (of cause it's only my experience and other environments may cause something else) AG has always switched in 2-3 sec and I've seen FCIs needing up to 5 minutes to get online again. So basically yes, both solutions need downtime to switch, but it's the different mount of the downtime.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way/features in SQL that gives a 100% uptime.

In AlwaysOn Availability group, there is a small downtime when a failover occurs as the cluster needs to switch things up (usually less then 1 min). All transaction that were active on the primary at the time of the failover will be rollback and needs to be redone on the new primary. SQL will not "transfer" inflight transaction to the "fail to" node.

If using SQL in cluster, there will also be a downtime while the service are starting on the other node. (usually a bit longer then AGs)

Even if there is no failover, there still could be all kinds of network glitches that ends up "disconnecting" your app from SQL.

If your application cannot deal with a disconnection, then I guess the work that needs to be done is at the application level (to allow your app to deal with those).

Reaching a 100% uptime is something really complex (and costy). To get it, you may need your application to talk with 2 different databases all the time, so that if one disconnect, the app still can do the transaction in the second (and queue a redo for where it failed).

Answer (score 0):

There will be an interruption of database connectivity regardless of the AO implementation (FCI or AGs) during a failover. If the app is using modern drivers (which have built-in connection resiliency) and is coded to retry interrupted in-progress commands when possible, the outage for a typical OLTP workload can be largely transparent end users. However, response time during the failover will be longer than normal. This can be mitigated with [Accelerated Database Recovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts?view=sql-server-ver16).

The interruption will only occur once when the active/primary node is failed over to an already patched node as part of a [rolling patching process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/availability-groups/windows/upgrading-always-on-availability-group-replica-instances).